# Como fazer um select pela data em c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Pretendo fazer um select pela data actual, do tipo: listar todos os dados que foram cadastrado hoje na minha tabela, eu fiz desta forma e não resulta em nada, não gera erros nem lista nenhuma das informações cadastrado.

```
//Método Listar registos cadastrado Actualmente
public List<View_Caixa> Listar_Data()
{
    List<View_Caixa> lis = new List<View_Caixa>();
    SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(caminho);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conexao;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    string li = "select *from view_caixa where data_registo=@data_registo"; //É aqui onde eu faço o meu select
    cmd.CommandText = li;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data_registo", DateTime.Now);
    conexao.Close();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    conexao.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        View_Caixa obj = new View_Caixa();
        obj.id_caixa = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_caixa"].ToString());
        obj.funcionario = dr["funcionario"].ToString();
        obj.caixa_inicial = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["caixa_inicial"].ToString());
        obj.total_veda_caixa = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total_veda_caixa"].ToString());
        obj.total_venda_multicaixa = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total_venda_multicaixa"].ToString());
        obj.total_multipagamento = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total_multipagamento"].ToString());
        obj.caixa_final = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["caixa_final"].ToString());
        obj.conciliacao = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["conciliacao"].ToString());
        obj.data_registo = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["data_registo"].ToString());
        lis.Add(obj);
    }
    return lis;
}
```

Comment: @Qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: Como está gravado a data no banco?

Comment: Estou a usar o SQL-Server, estou a gravar desta maneira pegando a data de forma automático : 
          
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data_registo", DateTime.Now);

Answer (score 2):

O `DateTime.Now` retorna a **data e hora** e no seu select você está pedindo pra listar apenas onde a data for exatamente igual ao que retornou no `DateTime.Now`.

Mude seu select para (Usando **SQL-Server**):

```
select * from view_caixa where data_registo between @data_registo and @data_registro2
```

No seu `DateTime.Now` faça isso:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data_registo", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"+" 00:00:00"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data_registo", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"+" 23:59:59"));
```

Dessa forma ele vai pegar todos registros do banco dentro desse período especificado. Mesmo que no seu banco esteja gravando sem a hora, isso funcionará, mas note que, dependendo do BD, você precisa passar o parâmetro para data. Se for oracle, por exemplo, ficaria assim o select:

```
select * from view_caixa where data_registo between 
   TO_DATE(@data_registo, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss') and 
   TO_DATE(@data_registro2, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
```

Verifique como está o formato da sua data no BD e como a query está sendo montada.

Comment: Estou a usar o Sql-Server 2014..

Comment: Fiz desta forma e nada:  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registo", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy" + " 23:59:59")); não resulta em nada

Comment: @AntónioMateta você alterou seu select também e adicionou os 2 parâmetros?

Comment: Sim, mas já a consegui dar solução deste problema, o problema esta no "Time", substitui o "Time" para "Today" fico assim : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registo", DateTime.Today);

Comment: @AntónioMateta bom que resolveu. Mas cuidado com o uso do Today, pois ele também retorna a hora. Mas isso pode ser resolvido assim se necessário: `DateTime.Today.ToString("d")`

Comment: ok, valeu a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Na chamada do método [`AddWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), o nome do parâmetro deve conter a arroba.

Substitua:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("data_registo", DateTime.Now);
```

Por:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registo", DateTime.Now);
```

Edit e P.S.: o George Wurthmann percebeu o problema maior no código. A resposta dele é a correcta. A comparação de data/hora com DateTime.Now não funciona pois é precisa até o milissegundo. Você deveria comparar somente a data.

Comment: Já fiz algo do género também não listou nem gerou erro.

Comment: @AntónioMateta pode haver outros motivos pelos quais nada é listado. Precisaríamos de um exemplo de registo da sua base para saber por quais motivos ele não seria listado.

Comment: Penso eu que deve ser por não converter a data em string, porque o DateTime.Now traz a data junto com a hora, se eu substituir o meu parametro :   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registo", DateTime.Now);        para: ele lista normalmente     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_registo", "2017-04-03");

Comment: Será que tem como coverter o Formato DataTime em apenas Data?

Comment: Bom pessoal, surgiu mas uma outra duvida, pretendo fazer mas um select, mas para visualizar apenas os dados cadastrado em uma determinada semana ou mês, como seria o meu select?

Comment: Eu sugiro criar uma nova pergunta específica para isso.

Comment: Já criei, só estou é aguardar pelas respostas.