# Como fazer um select em c# usando base de dado / Sql-Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Em uma pergunta anterior, eu precisava fazer um select por uma data específica:

[Como fazer um select pela data em c#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194656/como-fazer-um-select-pela-data-em-c)

Agora eu preciso fazer um select que traga os registros cuja data esteja dentro de uma semana ou mês específico. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Bom dia Antonio, a pergunta tem poucos detalhes, clarifique a pergunta com pedaçõs de código ou detalhe melhor a pergunta. podias postar a estrutura da view_venda para que possamos ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa da função [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174420.aspx) do SQL Server.

Esta função funciona assim: você informa a parte da data pela qual deseja realizar a pesquisa, e a data em si. A função retorna o número que corresponde à parte da data.

Por exemplo:

```
select DATEPART(week, '2017-06-04')
```

Este código acima retorna 14, pois a semana na qual a data 06/04/2017 se encontra é a décima quarta semana do ano.

Portanto, para pesquisar por todos os registros que se encontram, por exemplo, na vigésima semana de 2017, a pesquisa seria parecida com:

```
select
    *
from
    SuaTabela
where
    DATEPART(week, CampoData) = 20
    and DATEPART(year, CampoData) = 2017
```

Para pesquisar por todos os registros que se encontram, por exemplo, no mês de dezembro de 2016, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
select
    *
from
    SuaTabela
where
    DATEPART(month, CampoData) = 12
    and DATEPART(year, CampoData) = 2016
```